# Casting JSON to NSData in Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm trying to get the values from a JSON response into the format below, but I keep getting an error on `Alamofire.request`:

> Cannot invoke 'responseJSON' with an argument list of type '((*,*,*,*)->)'

I’m sure it has to do something with the variable initialised before `Alamofire.request()`. Also I’m sure the return will be `nil`, how can I fix that?

```
func annotations() -> [TestAnnotation] {
    var annotations: [TestAnnotation] = []
    var points: NSDictionary = [:]
    var json: NSData?

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://192.168.0.10/test/globe.php", parameters:nil, encoding: .JSON) .responseJSON
        {
            (request, response, data, error) in

            json = JSON((data as? NSData)!)

    }
    for point in json["glimps"] as! NSArray {
        let lat = (point as! NSDictionary)["latitude"] as! CLLocationDegrees
        let lon = (point as! NSDictionary)["longitude"] as! CLLocationDegrees
        let gid = String(stringInterpolationSegment: (point as! NSDictionary)["id"])
        ///
        let coordinate1 : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon)

        let a1: TestAnnotation = TestAnnotation(coordinate: coordinate1, title: gid)
        annotations.append(a1)
    }

    return annotations
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the way I handle the JSON requests using Alamofire, For some reason it's an issue I've too with the Alamofire request for JSON too :

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, urlTo, parameters: nil, encoding: .URL).responseString(completionHandler: {
    (request: NSURLRequest, response: NSHTTPURLResponse?, responseBody: String?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    // Convert the response to NSData to handle with SwiftyJSON
    if let data = (responseBody as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        let json = JSON(data: data)
        println(json)
    }
})
```

But according to your question you have an issue, because the request is **async** remember that. This implies that your code in the `for` doesn't work properly because it is just below the request, you can handle the request in the following way if you want it or just inside the completion handler:

```
func makeRequest(url : String, params : [String : String]?, completionHandler: (responseObject: JSON?, error: NSError?) -> ())  -> Request? {

    return Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: params, encoding: .URL)
        .responseString { request, response, responseBody, error in completionHandler(
            responseObject:
            {
                // JSON to return
                var json : JSON?

                if let response = responseBody {                        
                    // Parse the response to NSData
                    if let data = (response as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                        json = JSON(data: data)
                    }
                }

                return json

                }(), error: error)
    }
}
```

And then you can call it in the following way:

```
self.makeRequest("url", params: nil) { json, error in            

     //handle the error here if you want before

     println(json)            
}
```

I strongly recommend you using [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) to manage the JSON in a better and easy way, it's up to you.

I hope this help you.

Comment: how can I use json, outside this scope, I keep getting nil.

Comment: The problem is that the call is async as I told you before , you need to make like a handler to get the JSON and work with it in the scope.